# SWIFT reporting "Extra argument in call" - works in Playground

Tags: ios, swift, arguments, func

Under //Actions (line 16) I have a function call that takes two arguments and returns two variables. When I wrote and tested the block of code in Playground I had no errors; when I typed the code into Swift I am getting an error stating: "Extra argument in call"

I read through many other similar posts over the last 2 hours and i don't believe any of those provide an answer. I thought maybe I was passing the wrong datatype but it should be a String array and, as I mentioned, it works fine in Playground and I am following the examples in the Swift Programming Language eBook as well as Sams:Teach Yourself Swift. Thanks for any help!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Class variables
    var deck = ["A", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    var hand = [String]()
    var discard = [String]()

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var deckLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var handLabel: UILabel!

    // Actions
    @IBAction func dealHand(sender: UIButton) {
        var cards = dealHand(deck, hand) // Extra argument in call ERROR
```

The line above is where the error occurs.

```
        deck = cards.newDeck
        hand = cards.newHand
        deckLabel.text = deck.description
        handLabel.text = hand.description
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

func dealHand(oldDeck: [String], oldHand: [String]) ->(newDeck: [String], newHand: [String])
{
    var newDeck = [String]()
    var newHand = [String]()
    var tempDeck = oldDeck
    var tempHand = oldHand
    var randomCard = 0

    for deal in 0..<5
    {
        randomCard = random() % tempDeck.count
        tempHand.append(tempDeck[randomCard])
        tempDeck.removeAtIndex(randomCard)
    }
    newDeck = tempDeck
    newHand = tempHand

    return (newDeck, newHand)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your `dealHand` function to :

```
func dealNewHand(oldDeck: [String], oldHand: [String]) -> (newDeck: [String], newHand: [String])
```

And the call to :

```
var cards = dealNewHand(deck, hand)
```

The compiler seems confused because your IBAction had the same function name.

Comment: Ahhh, very subtle but that was it; good eye, Mehdi. I replaced the IBAction from the button and it works just fine. Your fast/accurate response is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have two method look almost same. Its confusing.

```
@IBAction func dealHand(sender: UIButton)
```

**AND**

```
func dealHand(oldDeck: [String], oldHand: [String]) ->(newDeck: [String], newHand: [String])
```

Change anyone, hope it will be gone.

Comment: Thanks, Rashad. The button was just for testing so I didn't give it much thought. Appreciate the response.